# KineticJs cannot draw image

Tags: javascript, html, image, kineticjs, onload

Most KineticJS classes such as Circle and Rect work fine. However, when trying to implement a Sprite with an image in my code, the program fails.

Here is the error that I receive:

[image: Error]

I assumed that this occured because it tried to draw the sprite before the image was drawn. Therefore I have put in an effort in order to avoid this.

```
var images = {}; // this empty object will hold later our loaded images
var imagesLoaded = false;

var sources = 
{ // we define here the list of our assets to load
    debug: '../images/red_player_1_standing.png',
    sprite: '../images/redmenwalking_down.png'
};

var loadedImages = 0;
var numImages = 0;

for(var src in sources) 
{
    numImages++;
}

for(var src in sources) 
{
    images[src] = new Image();
    images[src].onload = function() 
    {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) 
        {
            imagesLoaded = true;

            var DEBUG = new Kinetic.Sprite(
            {
                x: 300,
                y: 300,
                image: images['debug']
            })

            layer.add(DEBUG);
        }
    };

    images[src].src = sources[src];
}
```

Comment: Can you create JSfiddle?